# How to use a model after cross_validation in predicting a test data?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, prediction

I want to do the following:

- train a model using cross-validation
- use the model for prediction (test dataset)
- check the algorithmic bias towards some features values

I wonder if what I am doing is right? or there is another way?. Also, I have some feature that has many values. Is there a better way to split test data into subsets based on the values (like below split into male and female)?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
include_fesatures=all features except demographics like gender and region
X=full_DF[include_fesatures]# include_feature are numeric here
y=X.pop('target')

X, X_test, y, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=1,stratify=y)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
clf = RFC()   
c=0
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X,y):
    Xtr,Xte,ytr,yte=X.iloc[train_index],X.iloc[test_index],y.iloc[train_index],y.iloc[test_index]
    clf.fit(Xtr,ytr)
    y_predict = clf.predict(Xte)
    acc = f1_score(yte, y_predict)#accuracy_score(yte, y_predict)
    c= c+ acc
print ('Accuracy:', float(c)/10)

indexes=X_test.index
mixed_df=full_DF[full_DF.index.isin(indexes)]
mdf_idx=mixed_df[mixed_df['gender']=='M'].index
fdf_idx=mixed_df[mixed_df['gender']=='F'].index
mX,my=X_test[X_test.index.isin(mdf_idx)],y_test[y_test.index.isin(mdf_idx)]
fX,fy=X_test[X_test.index.isin(fdf_idx)],y_test[y_test.index.isin(fdf_idx)]

print(f1_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test)))
print(f1_score(my, clf.predict(mX)))
print(f1_score(fy, clf.predict(fX)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) generally is used to assess model performance. Usually, you will train the model on some part of the data (e.g. 4/5 in 5-fold CV) and test on the remaining part (1/5). This process is repeated for all folds. Also see [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf) (Chapter 5.1) for a good overview.

What you miss in your approach is [hyperparameter tuning](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). This is important for many models. So far you only train with standard parameter. One way of doing this (just an example, see sklearn docs for details) could be:

- Do test/train split
- Tune using 5-fold cv on train data
- Fit proper model with "best" parameter on train data
- Test overall performance on test data

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv  # noqa
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingGridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=y)

param_grid = {'max_depth': [10,50,100],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10, 20]}
base_estimator = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

sh = HalvingGridSearchCV(base_estimator, param_grid, cv=5,
                         factor=2, resource='n_estimators',
                         max_resources=30).fit(X_train, y_train)

print(sh.best_estimator_)
print("CV Score",sh.best_score_)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=50, min_samples_split=20, n_estimators=24, random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Predicted Acc." , round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred),2))
```

Comment: Dear Dr.Peter. thank you for the reply. Actually, my aim is to compare between multiple models or classifiers. I do not target hyperparameter tuning, just want to use the models with their default parameters in sklearn. In a paper, they mentioned they used a cross-validated model in checking model performance for groups like male, female in a test dataset. Since cross_val_score does not return a model to use for predictions test data later, I though of this way. what do you think? Is it right?.

Comment: Training a model on 4/5 of the data and prediction on 1/5 for each fold (to get a score) seems a reasonable approach to compare models